# Optimistic Locking for OneToOne Relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one, optimistic-locking

I have person page. In this page I have person, person_group, person_detail classes. I show person's information in this page with 3 classes. I want to add optimistic lock. Person is my main class. Person has one-to-one relationship with person_group and person_detail. I want when i changed person_group or person_detail, change person's version. How can i do?

Thanks

Comment: It can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909035/how-to-do-optimistic-locking-in-hibernate

Comment: Thanks but i know this. On the same entity's change, throw exception but i want when i change one-to-one relationship, throws exception